# LOOP in SAS with date

Tags: sas

I have posted similar kind of question of loop earlier.

Here I have to loop for 2011 to 2022, But for year 2011 the calculation is different from year 2012 to 2022. For year 2012 onwards the cost_2012 is depends on cost_2011 and cost_2013 depends on cost 2012..I tried with this code but am getting error msg.

```
%MACRO NFORE1;

proc sql;
create table  cost_news_&time  as

select  *
         ,case  (31DEC2011.d-EIS)/365<=10  then  Segment_0_10
                (31DEC2011.d-EIS)/365<=20  then  Segment_10_20
                 else note  end as cost_AGE_2011

,Latest_cost+('31DEC2011'd-Latest_cost_Date)/30.44*cost_AGE_2011 as cost_2011

%DO TIME=2012 %TO 2022;
%LET ltime=%eval(&time-1);

,case 
       ("31DEC&time."d-EIS)/365<=10  then  Segment_0_10
       ("31DEC&time."d-EIS)/365<=20  then  Segment_10_20
         else note  end as cost_AGE_&time

,case
     calculated cost_&ltime + calculated cost_AGE_&time * 12  as cost_&time

     from cost_news
;
quit;
%END;
%MEND NFORE1;
%NFORE1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data cost_news;
length EIS Latest_cost Latest_cost_Date Segment_0_10 Segment_10_20 Note 8;
run;

options mprint;
%MACRO NFORE1;

proc sql;
create table  cost_news_  as

select  *
         ,case  when ("31DEC2011"d-EIS)/365<=10  then  Segment_0_10
                when ("31DEC2011"d-EIS)/365<=20  then  Segment_10_20
                 else note  end as cost_AGE_2011

,Latest_cost+('31DEC2011'd-Latest_cost_Date)/30.44* calculated cost_AGE_2011 as cost_2011

%DO TIME=2012 %TO 2022;
%LET ltime=%eval(&time-1);

,case 
       when ("31DEC&time"d-EIS)/365<=10  then  Segment_0_10
       when ("31DEC&time"d-EIS)/365<=20  then  Segment_10_20
         else note  end as cost_AGE_&time

, calculated cost_&ltime + calculated cost_AGE_&time * 12  as cost_&time

%END;
    from cost_news
;
quit;
%MEND NFORE1;
%NFORE1;
```

Are all your variables numeric? Because you use them in such a way, including NOTE.

My changes:
 - FROM clause was repeated by the DO cycle - you only need one, right? Also QUIT statement.

- Changed `31DEC2011.d` to  `"31DEC2011"d`.
- added `WHEN` to `CASE` expressions
- Added `calculated` keyword to cost_AGE_2011.

Anyway, datastep programming would be much cleaner for this.